# Oracle BETWEEN from subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

Is something like this possible?

```
SELECT *
FROM [TABLE1]
WHERE [FIELDA] BETWEEN
    (SELECT [FIELDB], [FIELDC] 
     FROM [TABLE2]
     WHERE [set of conditions to ensure single record]);
```

Instead of doing:

```
SELECT *
FROM [TABLE1]
WHERE [FIELDA]
  BETWEEN (SELECT [FIELDB] FROM [TABLE2] WHERE [set of conditions to ensure single record])
  AND (SELECT [FIELDB] FROM [TABLE2] WHERE [set of conditions to ensure single record]);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option would be to move the BETWEEN condition into a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM [TABLE1]
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT NULL  
     FROM [TABLE2]
     WHERE [set of conditions to ensure single record]
       AND [TABLE1].[FIELDA] BETWEEN [TABLE2].[FIELDB] AND [TABLE2].[FIELDC]);
```

In this case it's not strictly necessary to limit the subquery to a single record. It could produce any number of records and the condition would be true as long as that number is more than 0.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. This is the option that helped me, as I need the structure of the query to remain separate in the "WHERE".

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might do:

```
with temp as 
  (select fieldb, fieldc
   from table2
   where set_of_conditions
  )
select *
from table1 a join temp b on a.fielda between b.fieldb and b.fieldc;
```